# ILUTP in sparse.linalg.spilu?

Tags: matlab, scipy, matrix-factorization

In Matlab, an ILU with threshold and pivoting (ILUTP) can be passed by default as:

```
setup.type = 'ilutp';
[L, U] = ilu(A, setup);
```

Looking for an equivalent in scipy, ex:

```
sparse.linalg.spilu(A, options = ??)
```

Tried to look up how matlab does the pivot and threshold but didn't seem to find much information.